# @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) - can i use serialized model throughout application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js

I saw in one example that you can encode a collection returned from a  controller and use it in your script files as a normal array of Json objects.

Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

```
 <script>
      var photos = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
 </script>
```

This was done in the cshtml view where the controller returns data. However, it seemed that the 'photos' was visible in other script files and could be used to populate backbone models with that data.
I'm interested in how this works, what exactly is going on under the hood. When we Encode in Json format models returned from the controller, is that variable cached and lives through the life of the application, and is somehow a global variable containing that data? Thanks

The code in Scripts/app.js file:

```
var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

var firstPhoto= new Photo(photos[0]); // first photo model of the encoded collection
```

Can i do this? As in, serialize model into Json in my razor view, and consume the model in different .js files in my application ?

Comment: your subject line does not match your question, what is your question?   have you tried the backbone website?  not sure what your really asking for here and have flagged this as too broad

Answer (score 0):

> Can i do this? As in, serialize model into Json in my razor view, and
>   consume the model in different .js files in my application ?

Yes, you can consume the model throughout your application provided it is in scope. There's not much going on under the hood bar your C# View Model being serialized to a JSON object.

> ...is that variable cached and lives through the life of the
>   application, and is somehow a global variable containing that data?

There's nothing special going on, it behaves as normal - if you create your variable on the window or document then it will be available to you everywhere. If you create a local variable it will be available to you only within that scope.

The convention would be to bootstrap your application with the information you require and store that information in your application namespace.

So, in your case, you'd have something like:

```
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    Resources: {}
};

// App.Resources.Photos = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
// So let's say your ViewModel contains an array of four Photo objects
// then your bootstrap object will look something like
App.Resources.Photos = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "Photo 1", Source: "mysite/photo1.png" },
        { Id: 2, Name: "Photo 2", Source: "mysite/photo2.png" },
        { Id: 3, Name: "Photo 3", Source: "mysite/photo3.png" },
        { Id: 4, Name: "Photo 4", Source: "mysite/photo4.png" }];

(function(){

    App.Models.Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // whatever you want in here
    });

    App.Collections.Photo = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Photo,
        url: '/api/photos'
    });

    App.PhotoCollection = new App.Collections.Photo(App.Resources.Photos);

})();
```

You now have a Backbone collection that is a direct representation of your C# View Model. There's no need to refer back to the bootstrap object any longer. Generally, once you have cast your bootstrap object to a collection or model you don't need to refer back to it, hence the term bootstrap - it's there purely for you to create your Backbone data structure.

You can read more about this [here](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) and [here](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data).